# Find and replace with sed and regex

Tags: macos, sed

I would like to use sed to replace version of assets files.

I have this on the file:

```
<script src="<?php echo assetsUrl ?>/ic-1548620973.js"></script>
```

and want update the timestamp with this command:

```
sed -i "s/(?<=ic-)(.*)(?=.js)/$timestamp.js/" src/views/partials/foot.view.php
```

The message error:

```
sed: 1: "src/views/partials/foot ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression
```

Comment: What is the original string you are trying to replace?

Comment: I updated the post, please take a look.

Comment: One more question, what is `$timestamp`? Is that a variable value you are wanting to place in there?

Comment: Yes, but the error is equals if I put a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` on `macOS` isn't going to do things like it's counterpart on `Linux`, so you'll need to adjust it.

```
$ timestamp=$( date +%s )
$ sed -Ei '' 's@(ic-)(.*)(\.js)@\1'"$timestamp"'\3@g' src/views/partials/foot.view.php
```

You'll need to include the `-E` option because you are using capture groups, and the look-behinds are not necessary not to mention the fact that `sed` isn't the right tool for that. As for the in-place editing on `macOS` you have to include two single quotes `''` after the `-i` option in order for it to save to the original file (in-place).

I changed the delimiters from `/` to `@` for readability. Essentially you have three capture groups, you'll include only the first and third one, while supplying the `$timestamp` variable in-between.

**Output**:

```
<script src="<?php echo assetsUrl ?>/ic-1548622266.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have `ruby` installed:

```
ruby -i -ne 'puts $_.gsub(/(?<=ic-)\d+(?=\.js)/,Time.now.to_i.to_s)' src/views/partials/foot.view.php
```

I'm not sure, but seems `ruby` was preinstalled in `MacOS`, right?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's/(?<=ic-)(.*)(?=.js)/'"$timestamp.js"'/' src/views/partials/foot.view.php
```

Comment: The error message is the same: "unterminated substitute in regular expression"

Comment: sed -i 's/\(?<=ic-\)\(.*\)\(?=.js\)/'"$timestamp.js"'/' src/views/partials/foot.view.php

Comment: Try to escape the brackets with a \ (forward slash) ... for all the brackets.. for some reason, in the comments, my forward slashes are not visible.

Comment: I tried this: sed -i 's/ic-\(.*\).js/\2019/' src/views/partials/foot.view.php
sed: 1: "src/views/partials/foot ...": unterminated substitute in regular expression

Comment: Would it be possible for you to walk through your original regex expression and its intention. What is it exactly trying to do .. if you don't mind me asking (I'm not an expert with regex, but I'm trying to help you debug)